# some issue when i try to use two CIFilter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, filter, core-graphics, core-image

i want to have a picture black&white the most clear as possible, for an app iPad et iPhone.

i did many thing for that :

1 - i take my picture with iPad's or iPhone's camera.

2 - i apply my first filter == CIColorMonochrome == and i display to be sure if that work.
my first filter work well.

3 - i recover the result of my last filter and i use it to apply my new filter == CINoiseReduction == and i display it to be sure if that work too ! but this time it display nothing so i don't know why.

```
      //CIColorMonochrome
    CIFilter * monochromeFilter;
    monochromeFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"];
    [monochromeFilter setValue:beginImage forKey:@"inputImage"];

    //Red Green Blue Alpha
    [monochromeFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithString:@"255 255 255 1.0"] forKey:@"inputColor"];

    [monochromeFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1] forKey:@"inputIntensity"];
    CIImage* monochromeImage = [monochromeFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    CIImage* outputImage = monochromeImage;

    //---===---

    CIFilter* noiseReductionFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CINoiseReduction"];

    //[noiseReductionFilter setDefaults];

    [noiseReductionFilter setValue:outputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [noiseReductionFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2] forKey:@"inputNoiseLevel"];
    [noiseReductionFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.40] forKey:@"inputSharpness"];
    [noiseReductionFilter retain];

    CIImage* noiseReductionImage = [noiseReductionFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

    // ---===---
    outputImage = noiseReductionImage;

    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[beginImage extent]];
    UIImage* newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);

    [imageView removeFromSuperview];

    CGRect imageFrame = [imageView frame];

    [imageView release];

   // [self noiseReduction:newImg];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:newImg]; 
    NSLog(@"%@ ===---=== " ,[self noiseReduction:newImg]);
    if (flag == 0)
        [imageView setFrame:imageFrame]; NSLog(@"setFrame image");

    NSLog(@"%@ ==== ", imageView);

    [[self view]addSubview:imageView];
```

cordially

Comment: CIColorMonochrome is Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later. not in iOS 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Not true. You can see the available filters via:     NSArray *properties = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBuiltIn];
    for (NSString *filterName in properties) {
        CIFilter *theFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:filterName];
        NSString *filterName = [theFilter name];
        NSLog(@"%@", filterName);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says "Available in OS X v10.4 and later." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346